# RandomSearchCV execution not ending when run a second time

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I'm currently working on a project where I want to run a RandomSearchCV with a lightgbm model.

I have no issues when running it the first. However, when i run the cell  a second time, the execution doesn't end and have to restart the kernel of my Jupyer Notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
import lightgbm as lgb
import time
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) 

#Parameters for RandomSearchCV
lgbm_random_grid = {
                'boosting_type': ['gbdt'],
                'learning_rate': [0.85,0.8,0.9]
                }




a = pd.DataFrame(data ={'col1': [-1, 1,1,1,1,-1,-1], 'col2': [-1, 1,1,1,1,-1,-1]})
b = pd.Series(data =[0,1,1,1,1,0,0])

lgbm_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = LGBMClassifier(), param_distributions= lgbm_random_grid ,  n_iter = 2, cv = 2,
verbose = 2, n_jobs = -1) 


%%time
c =lgbm_random.fit(a.values,b)
```

## Verbose return

[image: Verbose return]

When i try to run my cell a second time:

```
%%time
c =lgbm_random.fit(a.values,b)
```

It doesn't end. I tries to change `n_jobs` and `pre_dispatch` parameters with no success.

Comment: I try to run your code in google Colab but I receive this error: "NameError: name 'lgbm_random' is not defined".

Comment: your code is not giving complete information. Please provide reproducible error!

Comment: @ai_learning A line was missing, my bad, edited !

Comment: I tried with several others algorithm (Random forest gradient boosting,...). Works fine so I guess the issue comes from lightgbm only

Comment: I found a way to deal with my problem but didn't found the real issue:

`from sklearn.externals.joblib import parallel_backend
with parallel_backend('threading'):`

Before running my search.
Pretty sure I have an issue with multiprocessing. Therefore, I go with multithreading temporarily